# Apache Tika adds "wrap" new lines to document

Tags: pdf, apache-tika

If I use Apache Tika to convert a PDF to text or HTML it will add line wraps to the output.  Sentences will get broken in half and in the case of HTML a lot of `<p>` tags will get peppered in there.

Is there anyway to turn off line wrapping?  I'd prefer to keep the original intention of the document.

For example, the above would be rendered as follow:

```
<p>If I use Apache Tika to convert a PDF to text or HTML it will add line wraps to the output. 
</p>
<p>Sentences will get broken in half and in the case of HTML a lot of
</p>
```

where as I would prefer that it would be returned in one p tag.

For example: http://trevorgrayson.com/sandbox/CrossDocumentTest.pdf

Note the enumerated sections (e.g. 1. Definition of Confidential..) Tika will put `<p>` tags in for every line in the document.

Comment: *it will add line wraps to the output* - where are those line wraps? Are they where in the PDF the lines wrap?

Comment: They are exactly where the PDF line wraps.  If you copy and paste out of the PDF, or use some other converters these new lines won't be generated however.

Comment: PDFs do not necessarily contain information on paragraph starts and ends. So you usually only have information on line starts and ends (if even that). If you share sample PDFs representative for your use case, we could check whether they do contain further information or not.

Comment: Your sample PDF does not contain information on paragraph starts and ends. Heck, even lines in it are not obvious by structure, only by y coordinate: each individual glyph is separately positioned (with its own text matrix operator!) and drawn. When I copy&paste from it with Adobe Reader, each PDF line end becomes a newline control character, contrary to your claim in your first comment.

Comment: You're right, that's invalid. I generated a new one off of google docs and it's not what I was expecting. I will find an appropriate sample document.  Would you be able to clue me in to what you're using to view the PDF information mkl?

Comment: *clue me in to what you're using to view the PDF information* - for a first impression a text viewer, and then [RUPS](http://itextpdf.com/Products/itext-rups).

Comment: For whatever it is worth, we have had the same problem.  Also line breaks in pdf are sometimes left out and hence you get one long line.  For those we just added <br> where the html source had a carriage return.  You can try and replace the sporadic <p> with <br>.

Comment: We have had the same problem.  Also line breaks in pdf are sometimes left out and hence you get one loooong line.  For those we just added <br> where html source  carriage returns.  As for <p> sometimes they are missing, and sometimes they are in the wrong place.  So the <p> there pattern is less consistent, but tend to happen around bullets and numbered lists, so you can try to detect those.  You can also try and replace the sporadic <p> with <br>.  One HUGE CAVEAT however, with <br> added your html will not be responsive and <br> may force a return, when the window is shrunk.